# using a loop within setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so I have a object where the value for each key in the object is a list.
In my program I was using setState to pass this information along to get my application to do what it needs to do.
However I ran into a problem.
I have a function that takes an object as an input and so far the application works just fine when the value in the key value pair in the object is another object
such as {box: {...}}
Below is how it looks in chrome dev tools

```js
{box:
    { bottomRow: 0,  
      leftCol: 197.20770000000002,   
      rightCol:196.26864999999998,
      topRow: 183.7537109
    }
}
```

however sometimes this application takes an input where so far the best way i can get the information through is when the key, value pair is actually a normal key but then the object within the object has a key value pair where the values are lists
so more like {box: {a : [], b: [], c: []}}
below is kind of what it looks like in chrome dev tools

```js
{box: 
   {
   bottomRow: [0, 0.9259734999999978, 173.45592145, 166.3197615, 170.00889205000001, 0],
   leftCol: [197.20770000000002, 33.223985, 31.93761, 366.64247500000005, 200.74767, 
        371.60367],
   rightCol: [196.26864999999998, 362.29858, 364.735185, 26.710000000000036, 200.875, 
        27.97532000000001],
   topRow: [183.7537109, 191.74974550000002, 16.2172361, 17.120360925, 25.29426545, 
        210.521638]
   }
}
```

to my understanding you can not use a loop to iterate through an array for setState but i'm seeing some mixed answers.
My function that i need to read this information is simply

```js
displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box})
}
```

so im not sure if i have to give up on the method im trying entirely or if there is some way for me to iterate through the items inside the array.
So far all I know for sure is that trying to use forEach inside of the setState hook does not work lol

Comment: Correct if I didn't understood, *`box.key` sometimes has a value `string` & sometimes an `array`, due to which you can't iterate over it ?*

Comment: essentially yeah, it only returns numbers but yeah I can have times where the values are either numbers or an array of numbers and the application works as intended when its just one set of numbers

Comment: *Will the application work if I make all values of `box.key` to  arrays?*
`{
box: 
   {
       bottomRow: [],
       leftCol: [],
       rightCol: [],
       topRow: []
   }
}`

Comment: hey sorry i havent been able to check for a while, but now that you mention that way, like what if it was just a single value in each array i dont believe it would work

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> **Data is sometimes Iterable(array) & sometimes not (just a value)**
> I can have times where the values are either numbers or an array of numbers and the application works as intended when its just one set of numbers

**Solution :**

> You can push that box object's values to an array despite if its Iterable or not. If its already a array, i have used `flat()` which keeps them like this `[values]` & prevents them becoming like this `[[values]]` from happening.
> After that set state & map over the data !

```js
let x = {
  box: {
    bottomRow: 0,
    leftCol: 197.20770000000002,
    rightCol: 196.26864999999998,
    topRow: 183.7537109
  }
}

let y = {
  box: {
    bottomRow: [0, 0.9259734999999978, 173.45592145, 166.3197615, 170.00889205000001, 0],
    leftCol: [197.20770000000002, 33.223985, 31.93761, 366.64247500000005, 200.74767,
      371.60367
    ],
    rightCol: [196.26864999999998, 362.29858, 364.735185, 26.710000000000036, 200.875,
      27.97532000000001
    ],
    topRow: [183.7537109, 191.74974550000002, 16.2172361, 17.120360925, 25.29426545,
      210.521638
    ]
  }
}

let Result = {
  box: {}
}
Object.keys(x.box).forEach((i) => Result.box[i] = [x.box[i]].flat());
// COMMENT ABOVE & UNCOMMENT BELOW CODE
// Object.keys(y.box).forEach((i) => Result.box[i] = [y.box[i]].flat());
console.log(Result)
```

> ***If any doubts, leave a comment(i will update answer)***